# Facebook Comments Box: FQL for "total comments and replies" in comment

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm currently using

```
select time from comment
where object_id in
 (select comments_fbid from link_stat where url ='http://www.example.com/post/')
ORDER BY time DESC
```

to discover how many comments there are for this post (I simply count the responses here). This doesn't list the number of replies, of course.

Is there an equivalent FQL query that would count comments+replies?

Comment: A friend points to http://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=http://www.mediauk.com/radio/discussions/radio-chatter/virgin-buys-absolute-radio which is very useful, but unfortunately still only gives total comment numbers, not comment+replies. Any other help very much welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select time from comment where 
object_id in 
  (select comments_fbid from link_stat where url ='http://www.example.com/post/') 
or object_id in 
  (select post_fbid from comment where object_id in (select comments_fbid from link_stat where url ='http://www.example.com/post/'))
```

Comment: Thank you. I discovered exactly this mechanism.